# openconnect 18.04 "please upgrade your client"

Tags: 18.04, vpn, openconnect

I have been using my VPN connection successfully for a few months on v 18.04.  Openconnect reports its version as `v7.08-3ubuntu0.18.04.1`

Recently when I have tried to establish a connection, I have been getting a message from the server that I need to upgrade the version of my Cisco AnyConnect:

```
Please upgrade your AnyConnect Client
Failed to obtain WebVPN cookie
```

My question: how do I know what version they are expecting, and what version of Cisco AnyConnect does this version of Openconnect support/emulate?

FWIW - I have the Windows version of Cisco AnyConnect running in a VM, it is reporting as 4.7, and it still connects without a problem.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem at a client that profile based on OS.  They have told me they won't support a Linux client.  Here's my solution:

---

**Step 1**. Connect using official docs on supported system. Find VPN XML and XSD files for the VPN connection

**Step 2**. Set up a tunel and VPN with OpenVPN and Openconnect.  In this case we need to spoof that we are a
windows client.

Get the URL, and group from the XML/XSD files.  Get the UserAgent/version from google search and the
windows client.

```
sudo openvpn --mktun --dev tun1
sudo ip link set tun1 up
sudo openconnect vpnendpoint.com \
    --usergroup=group \
    --authgroup=group \
    --interface=tun1 \
    --useragent='Cisco AnyConnect VPN Agent for Windows 4.5.04029' \
    --os='win'
```

Provide authentication details as required.  The tunnel is now open.

**Step 3**. Close the tunnel

```
sudo ip link set tun1 down
sudo openvpn --rmtun --dev tun1
```

Comment: I could hug you right now but with the social distancing rules I can't :p, THANKS!

Comment: Also, for me a banner used to pop up in windows, waiting for accept/cancel. Same banner is shown in (text) terminal after providing authentication. It just looks like it is waiting for input, but after 30 seconds or so, I was able to access the resources through vpn.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this problem just adding `--os=win` like:

```
openconnect --os=win your_vpn_ip
```

Comment: I had an issue with connection on GUI, but this option with terminal solved it.